# Go back to debugging after created release version with react-native bundle (Android)

Tags: react-native

So I have created my Application using React native and just produced my first release-build.
My problem now is that I can't get back to react natives debug-mode.

By following the documentation, this is what i did.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/
```

This code generated the bundled `index.android.bundle` and `index.android.bundle.meta`

Now every time I execute `react-native run-android`, the javascript code-base wont update the application and I am not able to access the development(shake) menu in my app.

If I run `react-native bundle` again, the code will update.

I guess this is a simple issue, but can't find any information how to return so the app isn't using the bundled version anymore.

Comment: Hi, did u find the solution?

Answer (score 8):

- Delete assets folder in app/src/main/
- Remove this import line if exist : "import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;" in MainApplication.java
- Run "react-native run-android"

And boom!

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but I had to un-delete the Assets folder because 'react-native run-android' didn't recreate the folder...

Answer (score 2):

My quickest way is openning the file: $projectRoot\android\app\src\main\java\com\movies\MainApplication.java, 
going to the code like:

```
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
 return false; //it was changed to false from BuildConfig.DEBUG when released
}
```

then changing the false to true to make the debug menu available again.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with wrong import statement in MainApplication.java, 
You have to check if any  statement like `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` is in the imports. If so, remove that and run  `react-native run-android`

No need to delete assets folder